# why modprobe is not secure compare to insmod?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

In my organisation - Embedded system, we are asked not to use modprobe - the binary is disabled in the busy box. However, we are asked to use insmod for it. I don't understand the security issue in using modprobe. Can somebody please explain the reasoning? Thanks for your replies.

Comment: I can see no security problem there...

Comment: Dependency injection, maybe. `insmod` is a trivial program that only loads a module, `modprobe` is more complex, it can auto-locate modules and their dependencies, and this mechanism *may* be susceptible to injection. However, you need to be root anyway, so...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Why not make this an answer?

Comment: @alk, too many *mays* in my comment, and since root privileges are required in the first place, it's hard to call that a security flaw.

Comment: ask the guys who made this rule :)

Comment: Please see this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891705/whats-the-difference-between-insmod-and-modprobe) question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long time ago the way `modprobe` worked led to some security risks. Look [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/hh/hh-12.html#ss12.1) for more info. They have since been fixed, but the perception continues that `modprobe` needs to be avoided. Also in embedded world where software does not get updated as frequently there might be systems where this threat still holds.