# What happens in kernel when modprobe is given

Tags: operating-system, kernel, driver, hardware, insmod

I got this question for interview. I just know some firmware communication taking place. Once modprobe is given, an interrupt is triggered and kernel handles this interrupt according to priority and loads driver

I wanted to know difference between modprobe and insmod.

Comment: Nothing of what you wrote there is actually happening. Interrupt handling is totally unrelated to loading modules into the kernel. – Also the answer to this question does strongly depend on the kernel version. In the very earliest implementation of loading modules at runtime, a lot of the heavy lifting was done by the `insmod` program (called by `modprobe`) in userspace. These days (for security reasons, among other things) a lot of the work is done from kernel space.

Comment: "I wanted to know difference between modprobe and insmod" - On Stack Overflow there is a question specifically about that. [What's the difference between insmod and modprobe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891705/whats-the-difference-between-insmod-and-modprobe)